# Node js request module get different type (format) of return value from server?

Tags: node.js, node-request

I use request library to access web service, but I found that the return value can be different.

```
exports.getUserByEmail = function(req, res) {
    request.get(endPoint + req.params.email, function(error, response, user) {
        console.log((typeof user)) // type of user is string
        ... some logic 
    })
}


exports.login = function(req, res) {
    request.post(endPoint + 'login', {json: { email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }}, function(error, response, user) {
        console.log((typeof user)) // type of user is object
        ... some logic
    })
}
```

On the server side, it returns a JSON, e.g.

```
{
    username: "user",
    password: "hashedPassword",
    ......
}
```

Can anyone tell me why .get and .post method gives me different types of return value?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out, sorry about this stupid question. Forgot to set {json:true} as option in get method.